# How to create xml attributes dynamic via Map in scala

Tags: scala, scala-xml

I have one Map which contains some attributes, and I'd like to create a xml element which has these attributes.

e.g.  config is scala Map, and I want to use it as following, but actually the following doesn't work. Could anyone help me ? Thanks

```
<input type="text" {config.map(entry => entry._1 + "=" + entry._2)}></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the low-level API. This is what's generated by scalac parser when desugaring your xml literals:

```
import scala.xml.{UnprefixedAttribute, MetaData, TopScope, Text, Elem, Null}

val config: Map[String, String] = Map("k1" -> "v2", "k2" -> "v2")

val seed: MetaData = Null // Don't ask.
val meta: MetaData = config.toList.foldLeft(seed) {
  case (acc, (s1, s2)) =>
    new UnprefixedAttribute(
      key   = s1,
      value = s2,
      next  = acc
    )
}

Elem(
  prefix        = null,
  label         = "input",
  attributes    = meta,
  scope         = TopScope,
  minimizeEmpty = false
)
```

Comment: This is a lot of dirty laundry.  Maybe Scala could parse the `input` element, and then you could append the attributes?  Such code might be simpler.

Comment: Indeed, your solution is much cleaner :). The point I wanted to make here is that it's possible to understand the scala.xml APIs and use them directly. Despite a few weird cornes, they are pretty simple and well documented.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  Looking at it for a while now, I guess it's not as complex as I thought it was at first.

Answer (score 1):

Bummer you can't write what you wanted.  I guess the Scala compiler's XML literal parser isn't sophisticated enough to parse XML literals with expressions just inserted *anywhere*.  They can only be between tags or as individual attribute values.

As a workaround, it is possible to create the element with no attributes, or just the one attribute and the rest missing:

```
val elem = <input type="text"/>
```

Then you can add the attributes from your `Map` with a couple of copy constructors.

```
elem.copy(
  attributes = elem.attributes.copy(
    config.foldLeft(scala.xml.Null: scala.xml.MetaData) {
      case (next, (k, v)) => scala.xml.Attribute(k, scala.xml.Text(v), next)
    }
))
res1: scala.xml.Elem = <input type="text" k2="v2" k1="v2"/>
```

The above uses the copy constructor for the `Elem` and then one for the `attributes`.

There's also the option of just using one copy constructor and folding a little differently:

```
elem.copy(attributes = config.foldRight(elem.attributes) {
  case ((k, v), next) => scala.xml.Attribute(k, scala.xml.Text(v), next)
})
res2: scala.xml.Elem = <input k1="v2" k2="v2" type="text"/>
```

That might be the simplest option.

Although, Olivier's solution does show that `UnprefixedAttributed` will accept a `String` for an attribute value.

```
elem.copy(attributes = config.foldRight(elem.attributes) {
  case ((k, v), next) => new scala.xml.UnprefixedAttribute(k, v, next)
})
res3: scala.xml.Elem = <input k1="v2" k2="v2" type="text"/>
```

That avoids having to make a `Text` element so that you provide a `NodeSeq` value for `Attribute`.